# Is there a shortcut for adding fields to existing constructor in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts, code-generation

Is there any shortcut in Eclipse that allows me to **add** a field to the argument list of an existing constructor?

**Example:**

I hava this class:

```
public class A {
    int a;
    int b;

    public A(int a, int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

when i add a field `int c` (or many fields) i want to **add** it to the argumentlist of the constructor and assign the parameter to the field:

```
public class A {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c; //this is new

    public A(int a, int b, int c) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
}
```

i currently do this by creating the parameter manually and then press `CTRL + 1`and then choose "assign parameter to field"

but if i add more than one field at once this isn't really a good solution imho.

**I don't want to create a new constructor!**

Answer (score 9):

I would use the "change method signature" refactoring first (option+command+c on mac) to add the extra parameter(s) to the constructor. This way existing code that calls the constructor can pass sensible default as parameters (if you like). Then choose as many times CTRL+1 to quick fix the new fields into the class as you suggested.

Comment: of course it works :-) and yes, if Eclipse had anything better for your task it could be simpler... just imagine if we could write such tools with ease and add them as plugins like a breeze.

Comment: Shift-Alt-C on Windows. This is one of my favorite refactoring tools, and probably Eclipse's most powerful.

Answer (score 8):

To use this shortcut in Intellij the variable must be final and private.

1. Declare your variable as final.

> Ex: private final String name;

2. In MAC System the shortcut is Option+Return, i believe in windows is Alt+Enter.
3. Then Click in Add constructor parameter.

**Have fun!**

Answer (score 5):

Add a parameter to the constructor and press alt+Enter(Control Assist) and you will get an option to create field for parameter then press Enter. This is available in latest IntelliJ 2017.2.

Answer (score 1):

The only short command in that area, that I'm aware of, of is "generate constructor using fields", which is available when pressing Alt+S. Maybe this could be a little bit of help. Here is some further useful info on shortcuts.

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseShortcuts/article.html

Comment: this will create a new constructor. but thanks for the link! i'll have a look at it

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy any additional logic in the old constructor to the clipboard (none in your example).
2. Delete the old constructor.
3. Create new constructor with `ALT+insert` -> `constructor` -> `CTRL+A` -> `ENTER`
4. Paste any additional logic copied in step 1.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this

1. Right click the java class
2. Source->Generate Constructor using fields.
3. Select super constructor to use and instance variables to add to the constructor.

Comment: good idea but this will not work, because constructors with different signatures in the same class are no super-constructors

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse:

1. In Constructor select new parameter
2. press ctrl+1
3. select "Assign parameter to new field"

New field will be created in and will be set in your constructor.

Comment: I think the OP indicates this solution already and has requested something different.

Answer (score -2):

Use **alt+shift+s+o**. Generate Constructor using fields window will appear, click the **select all button** and press OK, you will get constructor with all the fields initialised.

Comment: this will create a new constructor

Comment: @PhilippSander: If this creates a new constructor, you just delete the old constructor. It takes a click, a drag, and a key press.

Comment: it don't want to create a new construtor