# ShortCut for adding class field to existing constructor in AndroidStudio or IDEA

Tags: java, android, android-studio, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

I have simple class:

```
public class A {
    private int a;
    private int b;

    public A(int a) {
        this.a = a;

    }
}
```

And now I want to add `int b` то constructors arguments and initialize class field with new argument . So it, finally, must be:

```
public A(int a, int b) {
    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
}
```

So, if `IDEA` (`AndroidStudio`) have shortCut for it?

---

**P.S.** Same question for `Eclipse`: [Shortcut for adding fields to existing constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931207/shortcut-for-adding-fields-to-existing-constructor)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Make sure, that field, you want to add to constructor is `private`
2. Select it's name with mouse
3. Press `Alt+Enter`
4. Choose `add constructor parametr`

Comment: plus 1 for mentioning that the field should be **private**

Comment: this unfortunately does not work when we already have getter/setter

Answer (score 1):

Ok Then you can do this to change .

> 1. Select the Constructor.
> 2. Right click inside Editor.
> 3. Click on Refactor.
> 4. Click on Change Signature and you will see this

[image]

Once you are there you can add or remove parameters and add new signature, rename , etc..,

Comment: Thanks for yours answer, but this way you can create new constructor, but cant modify existing.

Comment: Ok got it. Here is what you can do.

Comment: Interesting, but this way I cant simply add existing class field to constructor and initialize it with new constructor argument. This wat I can only add argument.

Comment: You can add it using overloading option but still you might not be able to acheive your goal with it i guess.