# Is there a shortcut in IntelliJ to add a field (without constructor)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

This nice [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19931207/is-there-a-shortcut-for-adding-fields-to-existing-constructor-in-eclipse) explains how to add another field that gets initialised via the constructor.

But I have a plain "data" bean. I want to add a new field, and then create getter/setter for that.

Is there shortcut that does exactly that?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You have to do it in 2 actions: you need to create your fields, and then use the shortcut to generate getter/setter.

Comment: You can use Lombok's @Data annotation

Comment: @BorisPavlović I asked how to broil a steak. Your answer goes like "you can also set your whole kitchen on fire". Yeah, that would do, but that is really not what I asked for ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat that's exactly why I haven't provided an answer to your question, but a comment that could be ignored

Comment: How will it know which field name, type and access to add?

Comment: @user7294900 It could ask for it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36673076/generating-java-bean-setters-in-eclipse

Comment: @GhostCat You could submit a feature request here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: I know there is shortcut to convert local variable (in some method) to class field (Cmd+Option+F or Ctrl+Alt+F on Windows) "Extract field"